# Use geojson polygon in geoShapeQuery in ElasticSearch 7.4 java client

Tags: java, elasticsearch, geojson

Does anyone have a code sample using geojson shape in **ElasticSearch 7.x** shape query?

It works when I build the shape using ES builders, however I need to use geojson passed in (see below), which likely needs parsing of geojson into ES shape:

```
{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[-82.30957031249999,26.657277674217585],[-81.7767333984375,25.84686509678058],[-80.90057373046875,24.986058021167594],[-80.25238037109375,25.16517336866393],[-79.97222900390625,26.08885491679362],[-79.771728515625,26.76277822801415],[-80.2606201171875,27.25707120788274],[-80.83740234375,27.332735136859146],[-81.529541015625,27.166695222253114],[-82.30957031249999,26.657277674217585]]]}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've been struggling with this as well though I actually wanted to feed a JTS Geometry directly to a query.  The solution I came up with was to use `WrapperQueryBuilder` to write the query in JSON:

```
import org.elasticsearch.common.geo.ShapeRelation;
import org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryBuilder;
import org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryBuilders;

...

String queryName = "...";
String geoJson = "...";

QueryBuilder geoShapeQuery = QueryBuilders.wrapperQuery(
  String.format(
    "{ \"geo_shape\": { \"%s\": { \"shape\": %s, \"relation\": \"%s\" } } }",
    queryName,
    geoJson,
    ShapeRelation.INTERSECTS.getRelationName()));
```

Answer (score 0):

My query shapes are simple polygons, so I ended up converting it to an array of points and creating a polygon out of these:

```
if (null != shape) {
   JSONObject jsonShape = new JSONObject(shape);
   JSONArray coords = jsonShape.getJSONArray("coordinates");
   CoordinatesBuilder cb = new CoordinatesBuilder();
   for (Object coord: coords.getJSONArray(0)) {
      JSONArray c = new JSONArray(coord.toString());
      cb.coordinate((Double)c.get(0), (Double)c.get(1));
   }

   PolygonBuilder pb  = new PolygonBuilder(cb);
   gsqb = QueryBuilders.geoShapeQuery("FOOTPRINT", pb.buildGeometry());
}
```